# Curl to get from api fails with (23) failed writing body

Tags: curl

I have to call an api that goes like this:

> xbox.timeTrack.com/main/data/1.0/search/id=adam54|pod=2017|country=US|store=Alaska

When i try to cURL the above as follows:

```
> Curl Https://xbox.timeTrack.com/main/data/1.0/search/id=adam54|pod=2017|country=US|store=Alaska
```

I get an error that reads (23) Failed writing body.

Any suggestions?

Comment: put the URL within quotes?

Comment: @DanielStenberg No Daniel, doesn't work